# Find and select checkbox automatically UIPATH RPA

Tags: checkbox, rpa, uipath-studio, uipath-robot, uipath-orchestrator

I'm using UiPath for automating a process whereby I have several dynamic checkboxes. I also have a variable that hold which checkbox is to be selected. How can I make UiPath to find a particular checkbox and tick it. By dynamic checkboxes, I meant that the checkboxes might change for each new form, e.g a form might have 3 checkboxes and another might have 10 checkboxes. This is not constant.

[image: click to view screenshot]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer:

Use the [Click](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/click) activity with an appropriate selector.

---

### An example:

For example, to check the box called "Turn on SafeSearch" on [Google Search settings](https://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en&fg=1):

**Selector:**

[image: Panel showing a strict selector]

Notice the `<nav up='1' />` segment that indicates an anchor. To do this, use the "Open in UiExplorer" button when setting the selector. In order to add a variable value instead of a static value, replace the string like "Turn on Safe Search" with a variable `{{checkboxLabel}}` after making the selector.

**Sequence:**

[image: View of the appropriate sequence]